# Embedding an html into angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, embed

I have written an html (complete with its css and javascript), but I want it to be in a proper form, so I created an angular app (with cli ng new bla). [The html contains a map if this matters.]
I did copy-paste into a component and expected it to work, but the page doesn't load. So how can an html be embedded into a basic angular app ?

Thanks

There are two scripts in the html as following:

```
    <script>
  var map;
  var beijing = {lat: 39.9664333333333, lng: 116.469033333333};
  var markers = [];


function initMap() {
  fetch('153-20070724234145.csv')     // Read the file under the given address
  .then(re => re.text())      // Extract the text part of the response
  .then(function (data_array){
    data_array = parseTxt(data_array);      // Parse the read string data to an array
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {     // initialize the map
    center: {lat: Number(data_array[1][0]), lng: Number(data_array[1][1])},
    zoom: 12});
    create_markers(data_array);     // Convert the array of lats and longs into a marker

    // Start visualisation
    var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');     // Create a new div in the html
    var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
    centerControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);

    // Clear Vis
    var clearControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var clearControl = new ClearControl(clearControlDiv, map);
    clearControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER].push(clearControlDiv);
    }
  )
}
</script>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=sdfkjjkf34kjn&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Comment: you just use a html file and link it to a component

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The html is complete with its header and tags (<html></html> etc). Does it need to be packed into a div or something similar?

Comment: you need to remove every tag except those inside the `<body>` tag else it wont work

Comment: cool, the div tag is loaded, but the other two scripts are missing. Do they need be transformed to typescript?

Comment: what scripts? can you add them to your question?

Comment: like those two tags

Answer (score 0):

Copy the HTML code in tag body to the `component.html`

Copy the scripts to `./src/index.html` before end tag body

Put your css in `./src/styles.css` or copy stylesheets to `./src/index.html`

Edit for Google Maps:

in yout angular project install google types

```
npm install -D @types/googlemaps
```

in index.html put before end tag head

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=changethis"></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
// your function...
}
</script>
</head>
```

in your component.ts (full example, only copy what you needs)

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('map') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.initMap();

    // uncomment for alternative
    // this.initGoogleMaps();
  }

  initMap() {
    (window as any).initMap();
  }

  initGoogleMaps() {
    const mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.5793, 73.8143),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
  }
}
```

in your component.html this is the map (alternative)

```
<div #map style="width:100%;height:400px"></div>
```

In this case, the simple path is: load googlemaps api => load angular app => load component => call your init function

Comment: Thans for the answer! I did copied scripts into src/index and div tag to the app.component.html and when i expect the code, i see that they are there, but the map isn't loaded

Comment: That looks like a pretty nice answer and i did you said, but there is a small problem. Even though i installed this types/googlemaps package, i cant import map from @types/googlemaps, becuse it can't be found. Might there be another dependency ?

Comment: In your component.html, do you have a div `<div id="map"></div>`?. The import must be empty {} in this case

Comment: yes i have and i have tried to put it in index.html and also in the html of component. In inspector, they seem to exist, but map isn't loaded

Comment: The only way to help you is if you upload an example in https://stackblitz.com and share the url